# cloning software raid 1 x2 drives of an ubuntu server to many other identical hardware servers

Tags: ubuntu, raid-1, cloning

I have an ubuntu server with x2 software raid 1 drives which took nearly 2 hours to set up.

The plan is that we need to make 10 more servers with the same configuration same hardware and number drives (same brand same part numbers)

I thought to clone one of the drives of the source server and restore to a drive of the destination server, will it work ? what should i use for cloning acronis? dd ?

Will there be any conflict to the other servers after cloning except the hostname? (ip address for now is with dhcp) as all need to be on lan at the same time

thanks